# Date Difference in ksh88

Tags: unix, ksh

I am writing a script in that I need to calculate date difference between two dates for that I am using this command

```
Date1="2018-01-01 12:00:00" 
Date2="2018-02-01 12:00:00"
TimeDiff=$(expr $(date -u -d "$Date2" +"%s") - $(date -u -d "$Date1" +"%s"))
```

This is working fine in other shells and it is not working in KSH 88.

Comment: I know it returns only seconds difference but that is fine for me

Comment: Unable to reproduce in either ksh93 or mksh. Maybe something changed between ksh88 and ksh93 that's affecting this, but not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Thank you Jim Stewart. Could you know how to do date diff in ksh88

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is working perfectly fine with `ksh88`.

**It would help if you state what OS you are using** and give more hints about "is not working" but anyway, I'm assuming you are testing that on a traditional Unix given the fact `ksh88` is extremely rare on Linux.

The issue is then likely not related to `ksh88` which perfectly understands `expr` that has always existed on Unix, and the `$( ... )` notation which `ksh88` even invented, but with the command `date` with which you use non POSIX extensions.

If `GNU` `date` is installed on your machine and accessible through its distinctive name `gdate`, you can simply use:

```
TimeDiff=$(expr $(gdate -u -d "$Date2" +"%s") - $(gdate -u -d "$Date1" +"%s"))
```

If the same script works when executed by `bash` but fails with *ksh88* while you stay on the **same** machine, the issue is with your `PATH`. For example under `bash`, your `PATH` has an hypothetical `/usr/gnu/bin` located first, while under `ksh88`, your `PATH` starts with a POSIX `/usr/xpg4/bin`.

Comment: Thank you for your response #jlliagre but even gdate is also not working for me it is giving me gdate is not found something like that error

Comment: @VeeraP Precisely, that's what I mean with **If GNU date is installed on your machine**. Unix/POSIX operating systems are not required to provide GNU tools or tools with a GNU compatible syntax, although it is a trend. You best bet is to retrieve gdate for your OS (it might already be there in a directory not in your PATH). Alternatively, you might look for an alternative, but you should give more hints about what your OS is first.